# How to make program remove lines in multiline textbox text - Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, multiline

I want to make a program that'll remove text lines if the line contains "0,00". I seperated the lines with "vbCrLf"  in the print function.

This is the function I came up with, can someone correct it?

```
Public Sub IzVrstic1()
    Dim arrLines() As String = TextOut.Text.Split(CChar(vbLf))
    TextOut.Clear()
    For Each ln As String In arrLines           
        If Not ln.Contains("0,00") Then
            TextOut.Text &= ln & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`Lines` array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx?cs-lang=vb) and [`Array.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd.aspx):

```
TextOut.Lines = Array.FindAll(TextOut.Lines, Function(line) Not line.Contains("0,00"))
```

Comment: Oh, I thought this will be much, much more complex. Thank you, it works!